# How to read then edit or append an Excel Files (columns and rows ) stored in Azure Blob Storage using PowerShell or python script

Tags: python, azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-runbook

I want to write an Azure Runbook(Powershell, Python) that will read an  Excel file that already exists in the Azure Storage account and append the data that is there and save the file back into the storage account.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by getting a blob with blob_service_client and storing the data to variable as below:

```
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="newcontainer0805", blob="source.txt")

#SOURCE CONTENTS
content =  blob_client.download_blob().content_as_text
```

Later we can add some data in the form of columns and can append it:

```
#INITIALIZE OUTPUT               
output_str = ""
#STORE COULMN HEADERS
data= list()
data.append(list(["column1", "column2", "column3", "column4"]))
```

Below is the complete code where we can get the data of a blob and add some content to it and save it in other container blob within same storage account

```
import logging
import sys
import os
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage import blob
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, __version__


def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    try:
        logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n")
        CONN_STR = "ADD_CON_STR"
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(CONN_STR)

        # MAP SOURCE FILE
        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="newcontainer0805", blob="source.txt")

        #SOURCE CONTENTS
        content =  blob_client.download_blob().content_as_text
        
        # WRITE HEADER TO A OUT PUTFILE
        output_file_dest = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="target", blob="target.csv")
        
        #INITIALIZE OUTPUT               
        output_str = ""
        
        #STORE COULMN HEADERS
        data= list()
            
        data.append(list(["column1", "column2", "column3", "column4"]))
        output_str += ('"' + '","'.join(data[0]) + '"\n')
        output_file_dest.upload_blob(output_str,overwrite=True)
        logging.info(' END OF FILE UPLOAD')
    except Exception as e:
        template = "An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
        message = template.format(type(e).__name__, e.args)
        print (message)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main("source.txt")
```

We can modify the above code according to our requirement for adding the content.